# Find the supremum and infimum of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $a,C,M$ be given positive real numbers. Define
$$\mathcal{M}:=\left\{f\in\mathrm{R}[0,a]:\int_0^a\Gamma(1+f(x))\mathrm{d}x=C,0\le f(x)\le M\right\}.$$
Here $\mathrm{R}[0,a]$ denote all Reimann integrable functions on the inteval $[0,a]$ and $\Gamma(x)$ is defined as
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{+\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t,z>0.$$
Find
$$\sup_{f\in\mathcal{M}}\int_0^af^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm}\inf_{f\in\mathcal{M}}\int_0^af^2(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$
I'm looking foward to your advices. Thanks in advance.